# How to do prediction with weka

Tags: weka, k-means, prediction

i'm using weka to do some text mining, i'm a little bit confused so i'm here to ask how can i ( with a set of comments that are in a some way classified as: notes, status of work, not conformity, warning) predict if a new comment belong to a specific class, with all the comment (9551) i've done a preprocess obtaining with the filter "stringtowordvector" a vector of tokens, and then i've used the simple kmeans to obtain a number of cluster. 
So the question is: if a user post a new comment can i predict with those data if it belong to a category of comment?
sorry if my question is a little bit confused but so am i.
thank you

Comment: unfortunately the class warning and not conformity have only 45 item (all togheter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Trivial Training-validation-test**

1. Create two datasets from your labelled instances. One will be training set and the other will be validation set. The training set will contain about 60% of the labelled data and the validation will contain 40% of the labelled data. There is no hard and fast rule for this split, but a 60-40 split is a good choice.
2. Use K-means (or any other clustering algorithm) on your training data. Develop a model. Record the model's error on training set. If the error is low and acceptable, you are fine. Save the model.
3. For now, your validation set will be your test dataset. Apply the model you saved on your validation set. Record the error. What is the difference between training error and validation error? If they both are low, the model's generalization is "seemingly" good.
4. Prepare a test dataset where you have all the features of your training and test dataset but the class/cluster is unknown.
5. Apply the model on the test data.

**10-fold cross validation**

1. Use all of your labelled data instances for this task.
2. Apply K-means (or any other algorithm of your choice) with a 10-fold CV setup.
3. Record the training error and CV error. Are they low? Is the difference between the errors is low? If yes, then save the model and apply it on the test data whose class/cluster is unknown.

NB: The training/test/validation errors and their differences will give you an "very initial" idea of overfitting/underfitting of your model. They are sanity tests. You need to perform other tests like learning curves to see if your model overfits or underfits or perfect. If there appears to be an overfitting and underfitting problem, you need to try many different techniques to overcome them.

Comment: so in case i want to know if a comment is referring to a problem i must first of all tagging all the comments i think they talk of a problem right?

Comment: i followed this tutorial for beginners, it gave me some ideas and clarifications:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gd5HwYYOz2U

Comment: Yes. That is supervised classification. I hope that my tutorials helped you.